# Python RE - Regular expression for matching a printf-like format string with escaped quotation marks

Tags: python, c++, regex, printf

I am writing a little C++ preprocessor in python, which should find printf-like format strings. What I need is a regular expression, which matches from the first to the second quotation mark, but ignoring all escaped quotation marks in between ('\"'). Here's an example:

```
foo(bar, "Value of \"s\" is: %s", "foobar");
```

I need a regex for:

```
"Value of \"s\" is: %s"
```

What I have so far is this:

```
(".*?")
```

But I haven't found a way to ignore the escaped quotation marks. I'm new to this. I would be very grateful, if someone could give me a solution/tip.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regular expressions are usually not very good at handling nested constructs, like double-quoted string which includes double-quote.

Comment: You could take a look at [Boost Wave Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/wave/doc/introduction.html) or [Warp](https://code.facebook.com/posts/476987592402291/under-the-hood-warp-a-fast-c-and-c-preprocessor/) to take ideas but i don´t think that regex are the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match the first all the chars between the first and the second `"`,

```
\".*?[^\\]\"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dI1xA7/5)

```
>>> s = r'foo(bar, "Value of \"s\" is: %s", "foobar");'
>>> m = re.search(r'".*?[^\\]"', s)
>>> result = m.group(0)
>>> print result
"Value of \"s\" is: %s"
```

**Explanation:**

- `"` Matches the first double quotes.
- `.*?` Matches any charcter zero or more times. `?` after `*` does a reluctant match.
- `[^\\]"` Matches upto the `"`(double quotes) which is not preceded by `\` symbol.

Comment: Wow, that works! Thank you. But could you explain it to me? What I was searching for was ignoring the sequence '\"', but your solution ignores just the backslash, or am I wrong?

Comment: Aah, so [^\\] acts like an ignore 'prefix' for the quotation mark? That would make sense. Again, thank you for your answer and for the explanation. Very appreciated.

Comment: `^` at the start of character class means negation. `.*?` a separate part and this `[^\\]"` a separate part. I escaped `\` inside char class. So it matches upto the first `second` double quotes only when the preceding character of the `"` must not be a backslash.